# mongoose express node JS link two collection without using _id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

hello I have two collection one called room and second called booking I have RoomID as a attribute and I want to link room id as a primary key from collection room with RoomID in collection booking in mongoose with express and node JS one room has many booking ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing such concept of `Primary Key` in mongodb (mongoose) but in Relational Databases like: MySQL, PGSQL and so on.

Even if you want to do so, you can use that in find operation simply like:

```
const bookings = await BookingModel.find({RoomID: inputRoomID});
```

This way you can get bookings for a simple room with `inputRoomID` and If you want to go further i.e. bookings for all rooms, go for `aggregation` in mongoose.